# Are these properties for a monoid enough for being the underlying monoid of an integral domain minus the zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, monoid, integral-domain

If $R$ is an integral domain then $R-\{0\}$ equipped with the original multiplication can be recognized as a commutative and cancellative monoid. The inversible elements form a subgroup $R^*$ and it is wellknown that each finite subgroup of this group is cyclic. My question is:

> Can any monoid with these properties be recognized as $R-\{0\}$ where $R$ is some integral domain?

Maybe you know some easy counterexample. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy counterexample: the positive elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ are  not only a monoid, but even a group under multiplication; however appending $0$ does not form a ring much less a domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any commutative and cancellative monoid $M$ that is finite and non-cyclic, or finite and for which $|M|+1$ is not a prime power, provides a counterexample.

Take for example $M=(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2$ to be the Klein four-group. If $M$ is isomorphic to $R-\{0\}$ for some integral domain $R$, then $R$ is a finite integral domain and hence a field. But then $R^*=R-\{0\}$ is cyclic, a contradiction.

Or take for example $M=\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$. If $M$ is isomorphic to $R-\{0\}$ for some integral domain $R$, then $R$ is a finite integral domain and hence a field. But there is no field of six elements, a contradiction.

Comment: The first example fails on the condition that every finite subgroup be cyclic.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether that was one of the required properties, which is why I included the second example :)

Comment: In Dutch English: 'I see this through the fingers'.

Comment: There come I pretty with away ;)